# element not selecting class

Tags: html, css, paypal

I simply can't understand what is wrong. Could anyone help me a bit? I am trying to customize the button, but it won't select the class.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="GAEUPE4GXM68E">
  <input type="submit" value="Instant Buy" name="submit" title="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online." class="paypal-btn">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


.paypal_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  margin: 0;background: #ff6600;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class is "paypal-btn" (separated by dash) and in your css you put ".paypal_btn" (separated by underscore)